# What does the offerThroughput option do when creating an Azure Cosmos DB container?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cloud-services

The docs provide for a few different ways of specifying throughput when creating a container programmatically. How are each of the following configurations different?

```js
// A. Create with default throughput?
const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({ id: 'gizmos' });
// B. Create with fixed throughput?
const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({ id: 'gizmos', throughput: 400 });
// C. Create with "maxThroughtput"?
const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({ id: 'gizmos', maxThroughput: 400 });
// D. Create with "offerThroughput"?
const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({ id: 'gizmos' }, { offerThroughput: 400 });
```

API documentation is very sparse on details...
[Azure Cosmos SDK for JavaScript | Containers.createIfNotExists()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/containers?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-cosmos-containers-createifnotexists)

Answer (score 0):

offerThroughput specifies the amount of RU/s or throughput for the container.

The JS SDK docs does not provide exhaustive explanation on this topic. If you are new to Cosmos DB I would recommend taking a look at these [articles on throughput](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/request-units) which provide much deeper explanations.

Comment: How is that different from the "throughput" parameter?

Comment: offerThroughput is just an older name for throughput. I would use throughput if you're using standard throughput, maxThroughput is for autoscale.